# Optimal method for parsing a keyed JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have objects being sent to me from an API (which cannot change) that follow this type of pattern:

```
{
  aaa: {
    name: "Aaa",
    desc: "..."
  },
  bbb: {
    name: "Bbb",
    desc: "..."
  },
  ccc: {
    name: "Ccc",
    desc: "...",
    stuff: {
      foo: {
        bar: "bar"
      },
      keys: ["foo"]
    }
  },
  keys: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is "flatten" these objects into more usable ones on the client.  So the result of flattening the object above would be:

```
[
  {
    key: "aaa",
    name: "Aaa",
    desc: "..."
  },
  {
    key: "bbb",
    name: "Bbb",
    desc: "..."
  },
  {
    key: "ccc",
    name: "Ccc",
    stuff: [
      { key: "foo", bar: "bar" }
    ]    
  }
]
```

As you can see there can be 2 levels of data I need to traverse.
Currently I'm looping through and creating the new object (brief ex. below), I'm just wondering if there's a more elegant way to handle this?

```
var myObjs = [];

$(data.keys).each(function(i, objKey) {
  i = $.extend({}, data[objKey], { key: objKey });
  myObjs.push(i);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is `for...in` not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you require:

```
function flatten(obj) {
    return $.map(obj.keys, function(key) {
        var res = $.extend({}, obj[key], {key: key});
        for (var key in res) {
            if (typeof res[key] === 'object') {
                res[key] = flatten(res[key]);
            }
        }
        return res;
    });
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/pgq2S/

NB: this will keep on recursing so long as you have nested objects - it doesn't currently stop at two levels.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function toArray(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || !("keys" in obj))
        return obj;
    return obj.keys.map(function(key) {
        var sub = obj[key];
        if (typeof sub !== 'object')
            return sub;
        for (var prop in sub)
            sub[prop] = toArray(sub[prop]);
        sub.key = key;
        return sub;
    });
}
```